# Problems parsing raw body from Typeforms webhook

Tags: javascript, express, post, webhooks, body-parser

I'm using the Typeform [webhook feature](https://www.typeform.com/help/webhooks/) to generate results to JSON whenever someone hits the submit button on the embedded survey, and I'm getting the results exactly as the documentation describes when I use a service like [RequestBin](https://requestb.in/), but when I expose my local app using ngrok via the command

```
ngrok http 3000
```

and then set the underlying route as the webhook target URL, I get unsatisfactory output. Here is the route in Express:

```
app.post('/receiveWebhook', function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.title);
    res.send(200);
});
```

Which yields the server-side output:

```
IncomingMessage {
   _readableState: 
       ReadableState {
           objectMode: false,
           highWaterMark: 16384,
           buffer: [],
           length: 0,
           pipes: null,
           pipesCount: 0,
           flowing: null,
           ended: false,
           endEmitted: false,
           reading: false,
           sync: true,
           needReadable: false,
           emittedReadable: false,
           ....
      body: {},
      params: {},
      ... 
      (can post the entire contents on Dropbox if comments think it is necessary)
```

When I hit the route using Postman, interestingly enough the only output in the Raw Body is:

```
{"title": "Test"}
```

which is not validated by the console.log statements in the Express route I posted above.

Any thoughts on why I would be receiving useful data through RequestBin but not be receiving it on the actual server-side of my local app?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're using the request wrongly (in express). The Typeform webhook will have the results as a body of the request, so you'll need to use `body-parser` to get the correct data.

Take a look here: https://github.com/TypeformIO/SimpleLiveReports/blob/master/index.js

**The important bits:**

Include body-parser

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

Use it as a middleware

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Use `req.body` to use the data, for example:

`app.post('/receive_results', function handleReceiveResults(req, res) {
    console.log('Got results!');
    var body = req.body;
    saveAnswers(body.token, body.answers, body.uid);
    res.send('Ok!');
});`

With this setup, `req.body` should contain the results of the submission. Let me know if it still doesn't work!